# wmic on remote computer, taken form list of computer name or ip

Tags: batch-file, wmic

```
@echo off
wmic /node:"computer" /user:myusername /password:"password" product get name > log.txt
```

how do i get ip's form a file and input it in node?

```
127.0.0.1 
more ips here ...
```

ip.txt^

username and password is the same for all the pc's im trying to reach.

i understand how the batch file can read form file, but i dont understand how to input it in the node.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ip.txt) do (
echo line=%%a )
```

might be a stupid question but,

```
     for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ip.txt) do (
          )
     wmic /node:%%a /user:myusername /password:"password" product get name > log.txt
```

just leave a comment if i formulated the question wrong.

ps: deleted old one

edit:

```
         for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ip.txt) do (

         wmic /node:%%a /user:myusername /password:"password" product get name > log.txt
)
```

like this ^ ?

edit edit: if i want to get more info from this command like graphics card, ram and sutch.

```
wmic /FAILFAST:ON /node:@ip.txt /user:username /password:password path Win32_VideoController get Name >> log.txt
```

to get the graphics card info, do i need an other line and change the get command or can i get a lot of info in one line ?

mabye like

```
wmic /FAILFAST:ON /node:@ip.txt /user:username /password:password path Win32_VideoController get Name,product get name, MEMORYCHIP get BankLabel,DeviceLocator,Capacity,Tag >> log.txt
```

if that makes sense

Comment: the closing paranthese `)` is the end of your `for` "Loop". In other words, what you do is: "for every line in ip.txt do (nothing). When finished, do a `wmic`". `%%a` is not declared anymore at this point. Take care, where you set the parantheses.

Comment: thanks for the input! so i need to extend it like in the edit ?

Comment: nearly correct. You'll need `>>log.txt` instead of `>log.txt`, because `>` will overwrite your file with the output of every single node, resulting in a logfile with only the last processed node. Also you might want to insert something like `echo ---- NODE: %%a ---->>log.txt` just before the `wmic` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah it's much simpler than that, my friend: http://ss64.com/nt/wmicglobal.html
          and  http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html

You can specify a file for wmic to operate against in the node argument:

```
@echo off
wmic /node:@ip.txt /user:myusername /password:"password" product get name > log.txt
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot! fixed my problem, but one question, if the computer im trying to reach is off, would it skip it or get stuck ?

Comment: Again, see the [this](http://ss64.com/nt/wmicglobal.html) page for wmic.  I've never had to do this in a script, but I think the switch /FAILFAST would be what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for your patience, very new to this. reading through the page now. thanks again

Comment: No worries!  Though I'm following up now myself and I'm not sure the switch does exactly what you want:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787035(v=ws.10).aspx  It won't hang completely, it will just take time and might give you some junk in the output that you might not want

Comment: not quite sure what you mean, but could i use /FAILFAST:ON ? lets say that something is invalid, like password is wrong or user name, would it just skip or stop?

Comment: It will never stop or "hang" if something goes wrong... To summarize that article, if you use `/FAILFAST:ON` then wmic will first try to ping each node and will only run the wmic command if it's online; and skip it if it's not.  In your original code example, you're redirecting output to log.txt.  If wmic fails, it will spit out an error message for that node.  I would assume you would want the log to show something that's offline, but if not redirect errors to nul like this:  `WMIC [...] > log.txt 2>nul`

Comment: ah i see! yeah i want it to show its offline as it goes down the list, but my next concern is how i can get more than one info in that line, for example could i run more than one command in that line or do i need to add more lines with different get commands? thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: you can get more values at once. Try (for example) `wmic product get name,installdate,vendor,version`

Comment: I believe you're asking if you can use multiple _aliases_ in a single wmic command... This, I don't think is possible, though I could be wrong.  You would need to employ a for loop as you were doing originally.

Comment: i will try, Thanks for the help!